# we get the Ejb home and ejb remote implementation at client side?

Tags: ejb

In some articles on different sites i read that we only serialize/deserialize the state of object.On the deserialization side actual class definition should be present.

If that is the case, In case of EJB then how we get the Ejb home and ejb remote implementaion from server(which is on remote machine) as on client side we just have home and remote interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the home and remote interfaces, you need "stub" implementations of those classes on the client.  These are generated in a vendor-specific way during application deployment, or in same cases, they are generated dynamically on the client.  In any case, the server-side implementation is never needed on the client: when a method is invoked on a stub, the method request is sent over the network, and the server executes the logic when it receives it.

Comment: Hi bkail i am under impression that the implementation for home and remote interface comes on fly from server  i.e on jndi.lookup we get the implementation of home interface and on home.create gives the implementation of remote object. Is this not correct? As you said these stubs may be generated dynamically on client. Are you refering the same process? If not can you please brief how are they are generated at client side?

Comment: In the internals of an EJB container there are several objects involved for a remote home and interface: client stub/proxy, server tie/skeleton, server home impl, and server object proxy.  From a client, you only need the stub/proxy for the home and object, and those are either generated at deploy time or dynamically using an RMI plugin (e.g., RMIClassLoaderSpi).  The server-side artifacts are also either generated at deploy time or dynamically, but those are not needed on the client.

Comment: Thanks bkail.Actually i am intersted in dynamically generation of proxy as you have mentioned using rmi plugin.My question here is can we send implementation of class (over network)as we have just have home/remote interface on client thru rmi? i am under impression that we send only state of object not implementation.

Comment: It is possible to send the stub implementation.  See RMIClassLoader.loadProxyClass.  There is a codebase parameter that can be used to remotely load stub classes.  Since it is transferring class bytes and executing them locally, it only works when a security manager is enabled and the remote code source has been granted appropriate permissions.